# Java program display the continuous output from Python

Tags: java, python

I would like to read the output from execute python script in time,but when I was doing this,java always waited the python until it finish(after 5 sec) all process.

I reproduced my question as following:

read.java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException{

    Runtime rt = Runtime.getRuntime();
    String[] commands = {"python.exe","hello.py"};  //execute the hello.py under path
    Process proc = rt.exec(commands);

    BufferedReader stdInput = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));

    BufferedReader stdError = new BufferedReader(new 
         InputStreamReader(proc.getErrorStream()));

    // read the output from the command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard output of the command:\n");
    String s = null;
    while ((s = stdInput.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }

    // read any errors from the attempted command
    System.out.println("Here is the standard error of the command (if any):\n");
    while ((s = stdError.readLine()) != null) {
        System.out.println(s);
    }
```

hello.py

```
import time

print "123\n"
time.sleep(5)  #wait 5 sec and print next line
print '456'
```

---update---

I rewrote my code as following,but it seemed doesn't work.

```
public class Hello implements Runnable {

    public void run() {
        String[] commands = { "python.exe", "hello.py" }; 
        ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
        pb.inheritIO();
        try {
            Process p = pb.start();
            int result = p.waitFor();
        } catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        (new Thread(new Hello())).start();
    }

}
```

Comment: If you are receiving the result all at once then everything is working fine. If you would like it to receive asynchronous messages from external programs then you will need to work more on threads and you will probably want to read about processbuilder

Comment: To help your further, try reading those:

http://www.javaworld.com/article/2071275/core-java/when-runtime-exec---won-t.html?page=2

https://www.java-tips.org/java-se-tips-100019/88888889-java-util/426-from-runtimeexec-to-processbuilder.html

Answer (score 3):

I would prefer [`ProcessBuilder`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html) and [`inheritIO`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/ProcessBuilder.html#inheritIO--), something like

```
String[] commands = { "python.exe", "hello.py" }; 
ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder(commands);
pb.inheritIO();
try {
    Process p = pb.start();
    int result = p.waitFor();
} catch (IOException | InterruptedException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

For your current solution to work, you would need to handle the IO in non-blocking threads.

Comment: This does not answer the OP question, it just add your opinion. (But I do agree on ProcessBuilder)

Comment: @Pfeiffer *For your current solution to work, you would need to handle the IO in non-blocking threads.* Note that OP is currently handling IO sequentially (and in one thread).

Comment: Sorry,I'm not really familiar with Java. How can I  handle the IO in non-blocking threads?

Comment: @李宗亮 You aren't familiar with Java, I am. I have told you how I would do it. Now you want to know how you can do it the harder way. Very well. Write a `Runnable`, see also [Defining and Starting a Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/runthread.html).

Comment: @ElliottFrisch Hi,thanks for your advice,I've edited my question after follow your suggestion.